# Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Function mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size() is deprecated

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to deploy my magento 2 project on ubunto ec2 instance and when I'm trying to access the website I get the following error

```
Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Function mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size() is deprecated in /var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Encryption/Crypt.php on line 62 in /var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Encryption/Crypt.php(62): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8192, 'Function mcrypt...', '/var/www/html/y...', 62, Array) #1 /var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(401): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Crypt->__construct('c79f46c31f6ec38...', 'blowfish', 'ecb', false) #2 /var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(313): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->getCrypt('c79f46c31f6ec38...', 0, false) #3 /var/www/html/yourParts/app/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Backend/Encrypted.php(109): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->decrypt('PayPal') #4 /var/www/html/yourParts/var/generation/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Backend/Encrypted/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted->processValue('PayPal') #5 /var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Config/MetadataConfigTypeProcessor.php(88): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted\Interceptor->processValue('PayPal') #6 /var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Config/MetadataConfigTypeProcessor.php(106): Magento\Framework\App\Config\MetadataConfigTypeProcessor->processScopeData(Array) #7 /var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Config/PostProcessorComposite.php(34): Magento\Framework\App\Config\MetadataConfigTypeProcessor->process(Array) #8 /var/www/html/yourParts/app/code/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\Config\PostProcessorComposite->process(Array) #9 /var/www/html/yourParts/var/generation/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader->read() #10 /var/www/html/yourParts/app/code/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System.php(223): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader\Proxy->read() #11 /var/www/html/yourParts/app/code/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System.php(180): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadDefaultScopeData('default') #12 /var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Config.php(139): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/sec...') #13 /var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Config.php(90): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/sec...') #14 /var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Config.php(103): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL) #15 /var/www/html/yourParts/app/code/Magento/Store/Model/HeaderProvider/Hsts.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...') #16 /var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Response/HeaderManager.php(41): Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply() #17 /var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(123): Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor)) #18 /var/www/html/yourParts/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array) #19 /var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(185): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse() #20 /var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(156): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleDeveloperMode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception)) #21 /var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception)) #22 /var/www/html/yourParts/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http)) #23 {main}
```

I've searched for that issue and I found that I have to downgrade php version from 7.1 to 7.0 but I need to solve the problem without downgrading 
magento version is 2.1.15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution guys. I opened that file:

```
/var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Encryption/Crypt.php
```

and I added @ before every mdecrypt line, like the following:

```
 $data = mdecrypt_generic($this->_handle, $data);
```

It will become:

```
$data = @mdecrypt_generic($this->_handle, $data);
```

Comment: adding @ is just a way to suppress the notice... its not a solution.